# Installing fonts

Tags: android, fonts, arabic, hebrew

I have a difficult time trying to install Hebrew/Arabic fonts on my level 7 (API 2.1) or "Nexus emulator". After rw mount/remount I can do it for level 3 devices, but not for Nexus! Why? What can be done? People using real physical devices already got this to work on the hardware.

That's what must be done for some of us:

1. We need system image saved on exit for tomorrow to continue the work
2. Open emulator to work in peace
3. cp command included with the SDK.

Please make me happy and give the chance to install the fonts. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I, for one, am not sure what you're asking.  Can you cut out the "why am I being given this problem" so that we can see what the problem itself?

Comment: Is this a programming question? Is this even a question?

Comment: I ams asking "How to install fonts in /system/fonts Emulator for Nexus device". I don't have rights to do it. Also Eclipse fails to do it.

Comment: This looked like it may belong on SuperUser, but it's about the emulator, so I would assume that Lazar is using it to develop software.